# Problema con límite para subir archivos en PHP

Tags: php

Modifique por medio del archivo .htaccess el límite para subir archivos

```
    php_value upload_max_filesize 30M
    php_value post_max_size 35M
```

Y tengo el siguiente código que envía por AJAX el archivo seleccionado

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

<form id="alta-curso" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="img-ingreso">
        <input name="uploadedfile" id="files" type="file" />
    </div>
    <button type="button" id="submit-button" class="guardar">Guardar</button>
</form>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('form').on('click', 'button', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var formData = new FormData();  // Crear un objeto FormData
            formData.append('uploadedfile', $('#files')[0].files[0]); // Agregar el archivo al FormData

            $.ajax({
                url: 'servidor.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: formData, // Usar el FormData como dato
                processData: false, // Evitar el procesamiento automático de datos
                contentType: false, // No establecer el tipo de contenido
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

En el archivo "servidor.php" el código es el siguiente

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {

    if ($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["error"] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        if(!empty($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'])){
            echo "recibo el archivo<br>";
            var_dump($_FILES['uploadedfile']['size']);

            if ($_FILES['uploadedfile']['size'] <= 500000) {
                echo "¡El archivo se cargó correctamente!";
            } else {
                echo "El archivo supera el límite de tamaño permitido.";
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Funciona correctamente recibiendo los mensajes esperados, mientras no se envie un archivo que supere el límite de 30MB establecido en .htaccess, pero si se envia un archivo que supere dicho límite por ejemplo un archivo de 31MB, no recibo ningún mensaje.

Podría subir el límite en .htaccess, pero si el usuario intentara subir un archivo que supere ese nuevo límite, no recibiria ningun mensaje, y establecer un control del lado del cliente por medio de javascript, podría ser inutil, si el usuario tiene desactivado los script de javascript.

Como puedo hacer para que sin importar el límite maximo establecido para subir un archivo, reciba el mensaje correspondiente

Comment: Si hay error, deberás manejarlo en un `else`, acorde a los otros [códigos de error](https://www.php.net/manual/es/features.file-upload.errors.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando el tamaño del archivo subido excede los límites configurados en php.ini o en .htaccess (en tu caso, 30MB para upload_max_filesize y 35MB para post_max_size), las variables $_POST y $_FILES quedarán vacías.

Si intentas acceder a $_FILES["uploadedfile"]["error"], por ejemplo, PHP arrojará un error porque $_FILES estará vacío. Este es el comportamiento predeterminado de PHP cuando se exceden los límites de tamaño de archivo o tamaño POST. En estos casos, la variable $_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH'] puede ayudarte a diagnosticar el problema, ya que contiene la longitud real del cuerpo de la solicitud HTTP. De esta manera, puedes utilizar esta variable para verificar si se intentó enviar más datos de los permitidos.

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {

    // Comprobar si el tamaño del contenido excede el límite
    if (empty($_POST) && empty($_FILES) && $_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH'] > 0) {
        echo "El archivo supera el límite de tamaño permitido.";
        return; // Termina la ejecución del script
    }

    // Verificar si el archivo se cargó correctamente
    if (isset($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["error"]) && $_FILES["uploadedfile"]["error"] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        if(!empty($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'])){
            echo "Recibo el archivo<br>";
            var_dump($_FILES['uploadedfile']['size']);

            // Puedes ajustar este límite según tus necesidades
            if ($_FILES['uploadedfile']['size'] <= 500000) {
                echo "¡El archivo se cargó correctamente!";
            } else {
                echo "El archivo supera el límite de tamaño permitido.";
            }
        }
    } else {
        // Otros errores de carga
        echo "Ocurrió un error al cargar el archivo.";
    }
}
?>
```

En resumen, lo que he hecho ha sido añadir un control para determinar cuando el tamaño del archivo supera el límite y terminar la ejecución del script.